# Многопоточность и asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, aiogram, daemon

У меня есть бот на aiogram, который должен, помимо отвечания на команды, делать регулярную рассылку (раз в N минут отправить сообщение).
Вариант с созданием параллельного потока-демона не работает (использовал threading)
Что делать?

```
from threading import Thread
def messages():
    while True:
        рассылка
msgs = Thread(target=messages(),daemon=True)
msgs.start()
```

после этого он входит в цикл в потоке и дальше не идёт
в отдельном тестовом файле аналогичные потоки адекватно работают друг с другом, оба файла в одной папке (если это важно, это папка с venv)

бот запускается

```
dp = Dispatcher()
bot = Bot(token=Token)    
async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: А создать задачу в шедулере  на рассылку не судьба?

Comment: если бы я знал что это такое, я бы попробовал
в следующий раз буду оставлять пометку об ошибке 418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед start_polling

```
asyncio.create_task(messages())
```

Сама функция

```
async def messages():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        Рассылка
```

И треды не нужны. Нулевой сон для разблокировки лупа.

Comment: этот вариант я не понял как работает, т.к. он один раз отправляет сообщение и забивает, а если поставить не 0, то не отправляет вообще

можете подробнее объяснить, пожалуйста?

Comment: может... с телефона писал, давайте вынесем слип в цикл

Comment: вы мой спаситель, это сработало